# D3 Parent Node index parameter returning Zero for additional enter() data

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I'm working on a bar chart style visualisation using the D3 library in which individual stacks are represented by the elements of the main data array, and the make-up of each stack by an inner array.

This involves two data joins and using enter() twice, which seems to be an acceptable method. Within the second of these, I am trying to use the third parameter of an anonymous function to make use of the parent node index.

I'm finding this works for an initial pass, but if I add data to the array for a new "stack", the node produced for the extra data is returning a zero as the parent node index.

Rather than replicate the full chart code, here is a stripped down example of the issue:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var svg = d3.select("#container").append("svg")         
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", 100)
    .attr("float","left")

function refreshAll() {

    svg
        .selectAll("g.outer")
        .data(data)
      .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class","outer")
        .attr("id", function(d,i,j) {
            console.log("outer array value '" + d + "' with index (i) of "+ i)
            return i
        })
      .selectAll("g.inner")
        .data(function(d) {return d})
      .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class","inner")
        .attr("id",function(d,i,j) {
            console.log("inner array value '"+ d +" with index (i) of "+ i +" and parent index (j) of "+ j)
            return j
        })
}   

var data = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5], [4,5,6]]
refreshAll()

data.push([5,6,7])
refreshAll()

</script>
```

The console output looks like this. The issue are the three `0` values at the end of the last three lines, which I expected to all be `4`:

```
outer array value '1,2,3' with index (i) of 0
outer array value '2,3,4' with index (i) of 1
outer array value '3,4,5' with index (i) of 2
outer array value '4,5,6' with index (i) of 3
inner array value '1 with index (i) of 0 and parent index (j) of 0
inner array value '2 with index (i) of 1 and parent index (j) of 0
inner array value '3 with index (i) of 2 and parent index (j) of 0
inner array value '2 with index (i) of 0 and parent index (j) of 1
inner array value '3 with index (i) of 1 and parent index (j) of 1
inner array value '4 with index (i) of 2 and parent index (j) of 1
inner array value '3 with index (i) of 0 and parent index (j) of 2
inner array value '4 with index (i) of 1 and parent index (j) of 2
inner array value '5 with index (i) of 2 and parent index (j) of 2
inner array value '4 with index (i) of 0 and parent index (j) of 3
inner array value '5 with index (i) of 1 and parent index (j) of 3
inner array value '6 with index (i) of 2 and parent index (j) of 3
outer array value '5,6,7' with index (i) of 4
inner array value '5 with index (i) of 0 and parent index (j) of 0
inner array value '6 with index (i) of 1 and parent index (j) of 0
inner array value '7 with index (i) of 2 and parent index (j) of 0
```

Everything in the DOM is nested as expected, in that the final `g.outer` element doesn't look any different to the others structurally.

What should I be doing differently to achieve a secondary join in which I can know the parent node's index, not just for initial elements, but also for subsequent ones? I'd rather not change the basic method I'm using here, unless it represents bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selection that you're operating on is the enter selection, which in your second call contains only a single (set of) element(s) -- the one you've just added. The index `j` refers to this particular selection (indices are specific to a selection). The index potentially changes with every selection.

To have a "global" index that doesn't change, make it part of the data, for example

```
var data = [{index: 0, values: [1,2,3]}, {index: 1, values: [2,3,4]}];
```

Then you can "propagate" the index into the values:

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.values.forEach(function(e) { e = { index: d.index, value: e }; });
});
```

Comment: I've tried to implement what you suggest, but I still can't see how it's possible. How would I go about accessing the index once I've made the second data join to one of the `values` arrays? At that point `d` is giving me the values from that array, `i` is giving the indices within that values array, and `j` will suffer the same "new selection" issue you explained, so I don't see how I gain access to the index. Can you clarify?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that you need to pull the index through to the inner elements. See my edit.

Comment: No worries - I had arrived at that conclusion so it's encouraging to know I'm thinking about this in the right way. I did very similar to what you've shown above except used the map function of the array inside the data join directly to transform it on the fly. Thanks!